# Reload text block from disk with python

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, command-line

Backstory: I have a couple of .blend files that share a single python plugin that provides a custom operator that renders them. I also have a wrapper script that I run blender with that calls that operator, like this:

```
# wrapper.py
import bpy
bpy.ops.render.my_custom_render_operator()
```

then execute blender like this:

```
blender "$1.blend" --background --python wrapper.py
```

Each .blend file has the python plugin as an external text block that is automatically registered on startup.
My problem that when I edit the plugin file blender don't update it's copy. If I were opening the GUI I would would open the text block and go to Text->Reload (or ALT-R), but I can't do that when rendering from the command line.
I need a way to reload all the text blocks from python, so I could put that in `wrapper.py` before calling my operator. I couldn't find a function to do that, although `bpy.ops.text.resolve_confit()` looks close.

Answer (score 2):

Auto-run text blocks execute before `--python` code, so nothing you put in wrapper.py will be able to reload the text block before the text gets auto-run.

I would disable auto-run (`-Y`) and either [execute your file with `exec`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_tips_and_tricks.html#executing-external-scripts) in wrapper.py, or (better) just install it as a regular addon.